# Correct AMPS & volts for DC motor controller

Tags: voltage, motor, amperage

I'm definitely an amateur hobbyist, but I need to fix something for a friend.

I have a existing DC motor and the controller is shot. The motor is rated at 0-90 VDC (5Amps)

I wanted to see if this controller would work.

http://www.batteryspace.com/dc-motor-controller-electronic-speed-controller-kit-for-90v-dc-motor.aspx

It is rated at 6 amps (Max). Will this cause any problems with the motors? They will mostly be running quite slowly.

I eventually want to replace the pot with an Arduino.

**EDIT** Here is the motor. Its old. Can't find any specs other than what is printed on the label.
http://www.lakecityelectric.net/show.php?motorid=20813

[image]

Comment: Please share a link to the motor itself, to make it easier to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: That sounds good from the information you've given.

Comment: I shared a link to the motor. Thats all i could find...its like 20 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller you have identified will work.

However, bear in mind that this controller is **NOT** providing any isolation from the line voltage. This is risky enough with the control potentiometer shown -- its internal insulation needs to be rated for this type of application, and many inexpensive units are not. But if you eventually want to control this with an Arduino or other microcontroller, **it will be up to you to provide the necessary galvanic isolation.**

Comment: When you say "risky", risky how? How can I provide the Isolation?

Comment: Anything you connect to the potentiometer terminals on the motor controller will be "floating" at line voltage, and must not be exposed for anyone to touch, nor connected to any other equipment (such as your PC). The method of providing isolation would depend on exactly what you intend to do.

Comment: This is a Rock Climbing tread-wall. I want to get it working again by just using the pot. Then once it's working, use a Micro-controller to replace the POT. Phase one, users will be turning the pot to get their desired speed, phase 2 will be using a digital pot and a Micro-Controller. I've done a lot of small projects with aurduino but this is definitely a learning opportunity for me. Any help you can provide would be great.

Comment: A mosfet would do it, right?

Comment: No, not by itself. But you could probably come up with a way to drive its gate via an optoisolator of some sort. It'll probably require reverse-engineering the motor controller's circuitry a bit to understand exactly what the manual potentiometer is doing.

Comment: k thanks. Do you know of any motor drivers that provide this isolation out of the box?

Comment: Here's an off-the-wall thought: How about driving the potentiometer mechanically with, say, a servomotor controlled by the Arduino?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8581/discussion-between-chris-kooken-and-dave-tweed)

Answer (score 1):

Motor you have is 0.5 HP or about 372 Watts. Recommended use for the controller is for 36Watts motor.

http://www.batteryspace.com/dcmotorheavyduty90vdcmotor36w2000rpm.aspx

1. Start up current spec. for the motor is missing.
2. Recommended use is for 36 Watts but as its is noted by you, it also specifies suitable up to 350 Watts. This is little confusing.

In absence of complete spec. for motor, you can consider these points along with electrical isolation issue pointed out by Dave Tweed.

Comment: Where did that come from?

Comment: Motor spec has rating as 0.5HP. Controller spec. has link for "Perfect use to control  MT-5400 90Vdc 36W motor".

Comment: That may be, but the specs are also fine for the OP's motor.

Comment: There is no spec for start up current. What are the chances that controller recommended for 36Watts motor works for one rates ~10x of that. Having said that, I agree, I shouldn't have made blanket statement. It is one point to consider.

Comment: You should edit your answer to make that point instead. Then I can remove my down-vote.

Comment: it says "It is suitable for 90VDC motor up to 350W"

Comment: I added an image from the motor itself, does this provide any insight? Also, do you think a mosfet would work for the isolation issue?

Comment: What controller seems to be doing is taking in 115/230VAC and using some active components (such as triac) to convert it to DC. What you need is isolation provided by transformer such that AC circuits and DC circuits are completely isolated.